# Reference needed for a result about analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I remember vaguely a theorem saying something like: Suppose $f(z)$ is  analytic on an open disc $D$ of center $a$ and radius $R>0$ in $\mathbb{C}$.  If the Taylor series of $f$ about $a$, namely,
$$\sum_{n}c_{n}(z-a)^{n} , $$
has a radius of convergence $0<r<R$, then $f$ must have a singularity at some $z_{1}$ such that  $|a-z_{1}|=r.$

Is this true? Would you give me a reference for this?

Comment: It is one of the many consequences of the Cauchy integral formula. If $f$ is analytic on $|z| < R+2\epsilon$ (that is given locally as power series) then for $|z| < R+\epsilon$, $f(z) = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{|s| = R+\epsilon} \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds$, expanding $\frac{1}{s-z}$ into a geometric series in $z/s$ gives a single power series representing $f$ on $|z| <  R+\epsilon$. Then show it is enough that $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions. (Particularly note the second remark after the proof.)

Comment: The situation you describe never happens. If $f$ is analytic in $D(a,R),$ then the Taylor series of $f$ about $a$ has radius of convergence at least $R.$

Comment: Is it also true for a holomorphic function of several variables?